# How can I find files NOT matching a specific extension in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, find, file-search

I need to find and delete all files in subdirectories that are **not** `.SQL` files. I can't figure out how to search for `<>.SQL` or `!.SQL` in Windows Search.

Most of the solutions that I've seen here are to find specific extensions and do something with them. I'm looking for the opposite.

Comment: yeah it's very easy to search for a specific file, but how do you search for everything that's **not** a specific file.

Comment: i can't search for <>*.sql or !*.sql in windows search ?

Comment: I do not believe this is a function of the Windows default search. You would most likely need to write a script or install a tool like grep.

Comment: I know this is way old, but this question http://superuser.com/questions/328223/find-all-files-that-are-not-of-a-specific-type-extension-in-folder has a brilliant answer. In Explorer search for "NOT *.sql" (capitalization of NOT matters) . It was new to me but I tested it and it works. You can even do "NOT *.mp3 NOT *.aiff NOT *.m4p". Even further you can go "NOT folder" to exclude folders from the results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do it from Windows Search, but from the command line it is:

```
dir /s /b /a-d | findstr /v /r ".*\.sql"
```

- dir /s - recursive directory listing
- /b - bare listing, only file names (no directory size info etc. in the output)
- /a-d - filter by attributes, not directory (remove sub directories from the listing)
- |  (pipe) - send the output of the directory listing to
- findstr - text search utility
- /v - only return lines that don't match
- /r - use regular expressions
- ".*.sql" - match anything any number of times followed by a dot followed by sql

Comment: You don't need regular expressions for this. After the pipe, `findstr /v "*.sql"` should work just fine. Thanks, though!

Comment: If you want to do something with the output of this command (e.g. delete the files), you can use this inside a batch file:
`FOR /f "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%a in (\`dir /s /b /a-d ^| findstr /v /r ".*\.sql"\`) DO del /f /q "%%a"`

Comment: This is good, and what I came up with as well.  It'd be nice to find a way to do this without using `dir \b` (so I could see date, size, etc) and without using a `for /f` loop.

Answer (score 4):

If you insist on using Windows search which doesn't have a native ability or support for such a feature, you could simply run it this way:

```
*.a OR *.b OR *.c OR *.d OR *.e OR *.f OR *.g OR *.h OR *.i OR *.j OR *.k OR *.l OR *.m OR *.n OR *.o OR *.p OR *.q OR *.r OR *.t OR *.u OR *.v OR *.w OR *.x OR *.y OR *.z
```

Following search will exclude all files with .s* extensions, while listing all others.

Perhaps there is a better way to do it, but this should work as well.

Comment: File extensions usually have 3 characters not 1. 26^3 = **17576** different combinations..........

Answer (score 4):

In Windows 10 (I'm on version 1803) I use the Search box in File Explorer and type

```
*.* kind:-jpg
```

to find all files which are not jpg in my pictures folders (so, videos etc). Perhaps you should try

```
*.* kind:-sql
```

Comment: This will also match folders. Your response and Jeff's comment on the original question led me to `NOT *.sql NOT kind:folder` which seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Curious, I tried my search again today and it did indeed include folders. So I modified my search to `*.* kind:-jpg kind:-folder` and folders were then excluded. Thanks for the update though @Amorphous