# Find all files that are NOT of a specific type/extension in folder?

Tags: windows-7, search, find

Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit:

I'm looking for a way to find all the files in a directory that are NOT of a specific file type or extension.

Example: I'd like to find every file that isn't an .mp3 in my music folder (and all sub folders).

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/209231/what-search-utilities-can-search-by-file-name-in-windows-7

Comment: Related, sure, but *not* duplicate. This is asking about the syntax for the built-in search, not specifically about a third-party utility.

Comment: Related: [How can I see the available Windows Search Filters?](http://superuser.com/q/531659/150988)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

type this in the search box of the directory you want to search

```
NOT *.mp3
```

Comment: How to make this work in windows XP?

Comment: This was new to me, but brilliant! After testing it, I want to add you can do multiples, such as NOT *.mp3, NOT *.aiff, etc. You can even do "NOT folder" to exclude folders.

Comment: But how to add several NOT conditions to a file type:folder search? Question here: http://superuser.com/questions/1001163/windows-7-search-multiple-condition-find-folders-of-this-size-that-does-not-co

Comment: Old thread, but there was a question to be answered.
@Guillaume You can chain AND NOT after your initial arguments.

Comment: Can you do this for multiple extensions? Something like NOT (*.mp3 AND *.wav)

Comment: If you are wondering why its not working for you, mind you operators like NOT, OR etc are case sensitive. For a file system that is case insensitive! Also these patterns work only in file explorer, they don't work in .NET APIs like `EnumerateFiles`

Answer (score 7):

From a command prompt you can pipe the direcotry list into findstr, and use findstr's `V` switch to exclude lines like the filter (in this case, lines ending in `.mp3`), as well as the `I` switch to make the find procedure case-insensitive.

```
dir | findstr /vi "*.mp3"
```

Answer (score 3):

I just open the folder with Windows Explorer, add the Type column to the display, and sort on it.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Get [FindUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm).
Step 2: `find some\dir -type f ! -name *.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
xcopy /L /EXCLUDE:.mp3 /S DIRNAME .
```

The /L flag forces xcopy to only list but not copy  the /s runs through all subfolders and the exclude misses out mp3s

Answer (score 0):

For a quick look I sort by clicking on the type column header in Explorer. There is a pull down option to tick boxes for only the files you want listed.

Answer (score 0):

You can check a mime-type with:

```
file -i <YourFile> -F "::" | sed 's/.*:: //' | sed 's/;.*//'
```

and then write a script.