# windows 7 search: multiple condition "find folders of this size that does not contain this and that"

Tags: windows-7, search, windows-search, conditional-statements

Windows 7 search allows to find specific files type and [exclude some](https://superuser.com/questions/328223/find-all-files-that-are-not-of-a-specific-type-extension-in-folder) using some operators (such as AND OR NOT) but **how to add multiple search condition** on these following example?

Ex 1: this query doesn't work: `type:folder size:tiny`

EX 2: searching FOLDERS that doesn't contain an extensions with this query doesn't work either: `type:folder NOT *.avi`

Ex 3: thus, searching FOLDERS that doesn't contain this or this extensions could not work:
`type:folder NOT *.avi NOT *rar`  or `type:folder NOT(*.avi *rar)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AND is what you want.

NOT *.jpg AND NOT *.rar AND NOT type:folder

will give you everything in a folder and subfolders that are not a jpg or rar and will also not show you the folders

Comment: For anyone arriving here looking for the answer on Windows 10, this answer should be altered to NOT *.jpg AND NOT *.rar AND NOT kind:folder